# How do you hide notification/title bar in an AS3/Air Android App?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm using FlashDevelop to create a simple Adobe AS3/Air game for Android and can't figure out how to hide the notification bar. I'm sure it's something easy that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application xml file, you need to set the `<fullScreen>` xml element to true:

```
<application>
    ...
    <initialWindow>
        ...
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        ...
    </initialWindow>
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps and get hide notification bar

Modify main Windowed Application tag as below:

```
 <mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" showNotificationbar="false" showTitleBar="false">
```

Open AIR application’s configuration xml file that gets generated automatically while creating new application.

uncomment this line. Change should look like below:

```
    <systemChrome></systemChrome>
```

Modify the above mentioned line to match the following:

```
    <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
```

That's it….

Comment: Are you sure this is how it is supposed to be done for Android Air? There is no "WindowedApplication" tag in the android air project's application.xml. I tried putting the "showNotificationbar" and "showTitleBar" tags in its application tag, but it said that it does not recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **starling**, you can also call this during runtime:

```
   Starling.current.nativeStage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

In starling, when you lose application context (e.g. while using **CameraRoll**), status bar may be shown even if you have following lines in your app-description xml:

```
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
```

Solution of this, is to call same line again after losing context:

```
   Starling.current.nativeStage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

Hope it helps.